# fatal error Firebase Snapshot

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everytime I run this I get this error: fatal error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 2017-09-15
>   06:30:04.650075+0200 RollerBank[845:211470] fatal error: unexpectedly
>   found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I have no idea what I have been doing wrong. Can someone help me please?

```
func reload(){
            //get data
            Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in



                for item in snapshot.children{

                    if let itemDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {


                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()


                        annotation.title = itemDict["TypeControle"] as! String
                        let tijd = itemDict["Tijd"] as! String
                        annotation.subtitle = "Geplaatst om \(tijd)"


                        let getLatitude = itemDict["Latitude"] as! Double
                        let getLongitude = itemDict["Longitude"] as! Double

                        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: getLatitude, longitude: getLongitude)

                        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

[image: Structure]

Comment: can u paste the structure of "Rollerbanken"?

Comment: I have my question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to parse value received from Firebase.

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {

    for key in value.keys {
            if let itemDict = value[key] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = itemDict["TypeControle"] as! String
                let tijd = itemDict["Tijd"] as! String
                annotation.subtitle = "Geplaatst om \(tijd)"

                let getLatitude = itemDict["Latitude"] as? String
                let getLongitude = itemDict["Longitude"] as? String
                if let lat = getLatitude, let long = getLongitude {
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat), longitude: Double(long))

                  self.map.addAnnotation(annotation) 
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have now a different error: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b2ce3f70) to 'NSNumber' (0x1b2cf0b38).
2017-09-15 07:14:30.180612+0200 RollerBank[898:224284] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b2ce3f70) to 'NSNumber' (0x1b2cf0b38).

Comment: On which line you receive this error ? Also check your dataType once.

Comment: I think you receive this crash when you try to fetch Latitude, Longitude. As per your db structure, they are string values, while you cast those as Double.

Comment: They are Double and i convert them to String because otherwise i cant save them in the database. newStory.Latitude = String(lat)
            newStory.Longitude = String(long)

Comment: The error is on line:  let getLatitude = itemDict["Latitude"] as! Double

Comment: Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'

Comment: Line: if let lat = Double(getLatitude), let long = Double(getLongitude) {
                                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

Comment: Edited again. I am not on my system, so i can't compile this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with this line

```
if let itemDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

You're making your itemDict a dictionary of the entire object.  So you don't have a key of "TypeControle", you have a key of the generated Firebase id.  You can get the child.value to get the dictionary you are looking for I believe.

```
if let itemDict = item.value as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: I get a error.. : Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
for item in snapshot.children {

    let snapshotValue = item.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    key  = snapshotValue["TypeControle"] as! String
    tijd = snapshotValue["tijd "] as! String
    // etc..
}
```

Hope it helps